# How to use a Scala Map[Any,Any]

Tags: scala, polymorphism

I am very confused about why Scala doesn't allow things that it should be able to infer. If I want to store arbitrary types in a Map I imagine this should be possible but am blocked where there seems to be enough information to perform the operation.

```
scala> var m: Map[Any, Any] = Map()
m: Map[Any,Any] = Map()

scala> m = ("one" -> 1, 2 -> "two", 3 -> 3)
<console>:8: error: type mismatch;
 found   : ((String, Int), (Int, String), (Int, Int))
 required: Map[Any,Any]
       m = ("one" -> 1, 2 -> "two", 3 -> 3)
           ^

scala> m += ("one" -> 1)

scala> m += (2 -> "two")

scala> m += (3 -> 3)

scala> m
res25: Map[Any,Any] = Map(one -> 1, 2 -> two, 3 -> 3)

scala> m("one").getClass
res26: Class[_] = class java.lang.Integer

scala> m(3).getClass
res27: Class[_] = class java.lang.Integer

scala> val result = m("one")+m(3)
<console>:8: error: type mismatch;
 found   : Any
 required: String
       val result = m("one")+m(3)
                              ^

scala> val result: Int = m("one")+m(3)
<console>:8: error: type mismatch;
 found   : Any
 required: String
       val result: Int = m("one")+m(3)
                                   ^

scala> val mr1 = m("one")
mr1: Any = 1

scala> val mr1 = m("one") => Int
<console>:1: error: not a legal formal parameter.
Note: Tuples cannot be directly destructured in method or function parameters.
      Either create a single parameter accepting the Tuple1,
      or consider a pattern matching anonymous function: `{ case (param1, param1) => ... }
       val mr1 = m("one") => Int
                  ^
```

Ultimately I do know the type of the Key (String), and since the value's real types are known, I should be at least able to cast them, right? I also realize the code has to be type safe.

I'm clearly doing trial and mostly error here, can anyone offer guidance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In

```
m = ("one" -> 1, 2 -> "two", 3 -> 3)
```

you are trying to assign to `m` so the right-hand side must be compatible with `Map[Any, Any]`. However, `("one" -> 1, 2 -> "two", 3 -> 3)` is a tuple which is not compatible, hence the error.

In

```
m += ("one" -> 1)
```

you are calling the `+` method of `Map[Any, Any]` with a `Tuple2[Any, Any]` argument. While `("one" -> 1)` has type `(String, Int)` this is compatible with `(Any, Any)` so they can be added individually.

Note you can also do:

```
m += ("one" -> 1, 2 -> "two", 3 -> 3)
```

When you lookup elements in the map, the type of the return value is `Any`, so the types of `m("one")` and `m(3)` are both `Any`. Since `Any` has no `+` operator, `m("one")+m(3)` will not compile. If you know both values are `Int`s then you can cast them:

```
m("one").asInstanceOf[Int] +m(3).asInstanceOf[Int]
```

Comment: Yeah, more trial and error I found. `var mr2 = mr1.asInstanceOf[java.lang.Integer]`

Answer (score 3):

This is wrong:

```
m = ("one" -> 1, 2 -> "two", 3 -> 3)
```

You are trying to assign a `Tuple3` to `m`, which you declared as a `Map[Any,Any]`.  You meant:

```
m = Map("one" -> 1, 2 -> "two", 3 -> 3)
```

However, it's worth noting that a having things of type `Any` in your code is almost certainly a bad idea.  Type-safety is great and is one of the major benefits of using Scala.  You should take advantage of it.